Higher Extensions and Cohomology
Let $\mathfrak{g}$ be a Lie algebra (over a field $k$) and $A$ e $B$ be $\mathfrak{g}-$módules, there is a   well-know bijection
$$
H^1(\mathfrak{g}, \mathrm{Hom}_k(A,B)) \simeq E^1(A,B) = \{SES   \quad 0 \to B \to E \to A \to 0\}/\sim
$$
to equivalent classes of extensions of A by B. Let $E^n(A,B)$ be n-fold extensions of A by B module some equivalent relation (as here), I want a explicit bijection
$$
H^n(\mathfrak{g}, \mathrm{Hom}_k(A,B)) \simeq E^n(A,B)
$$
I know there is such bijection using

$H^n(\mathfrak{g}, V) \simeq \mathrm{Ext}_{U(\mathfrak{g})}(k, V)$
$\mathrm{Ext}_{U(\mathfrak{g})}(k, \mathrm{Hom}_k(A,B)) \simeq \mathrm{Ext}_{U(\mathfrak{g})}(A, B)$   (just because any $U(\mathfrak{g})-$module is flat)
$\mathrm{Ext}_{U(\mathfrak{g})}(A,B) \simeq E^n (A,B)$    (holds in any abelian category with enought projectives, see  section IV.9 of Hilton & Stammbach, A course in homological algebra)

Context:
I want to work with extensions in categories without projectives/injectives.

My try:
I have an idea to cookup a map $\psi: E^n(A,B) \to \mathrm{Hom}(\mathfrak{g}^{\otimes n}, \mathrm{Hom}(A,B))$. Given an exact sequence
$$
E: \quad 0 \to B \to_{f_{n+1}} E_n  \to_{f_{n}} \cdots \to_{f_{2}} E_1 \to_{f_{1}} A \to 0
$$
Let $K_l = \ker f_l = f_{l+1}(E_{l+1})$, choose $s_l: K_l \to E_{l+1}$ a linear map such that $f_l \circ s_l = \mathrm{id}$. Given $x_1, \cdots, x_n \in \mathfrak{g}$ and $a \in A$, define
$$
\theta_1 (x_1, a) = x_1 s_1(a) - s_1(x_1a)  \in K_1\\
\theta_2 (x_2, x_1, a) = x_2 s_2( \theta_1(x_1, a) ) - s_2(x_2  \theta_{1}(x_1, a) )  \in K_2\\
\cdots\\
\theta_n (x_n, \cdots, x_1, a) = x_n s_n( \theta_{n-1}(x_{n-1}, \cdots, x_1, a) ) - s_n(x_n  \theta_{n-1}(x_{n-1}, \cdots, x_1, a) )  \in K_n = B\\
$$
and $\psi([E]) = [\theta_n]$. I have to verify that $\theta_n$ is alternating (maybe it is not? idk) and $[\theta]$ do not depend on those choices of $s_l$ and the exact sequence (only it's class).
But first of all, I would like to see that this $\psi$ is a bijection. Given a class in $\mathrm{Hom}^n(\mathfrak{g}, \mathrm{Hom}(A,B))$, I have no idea how to produce an n-fold extension.
